# Helper Function in JS

Tags: javascript

I am pretty beginner level in Javascript. How can I use helper function with this code. Thanks

```
module.exports.selectDate = function(browser, done, date) {
  const css = `div[data-autobot-element-id=DATEPICKER_DAY_${dateformat(date, 'yyyymmdd')}]`;
  browser
    .clickWaitForElementByCssWithCatch(css, isDisplayed, 30000, 1000)
    .nodeify(done);
};
```

Comment: A helper function to do what?

Comment: I have two dates- Pickup and Drop off. Both has the same functionality. To reduce the duplicity of the code I wanted to use helper function.

Comment: Where does this code specify whether it's matching the pickup or dropoff date?

Comment: I will just change the select date to Pickup date and drop off date. Rest of the code will be same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the function separately, and then assign it to multiple `module.exports` properties:

```
function dateFunc(browser, done, date) {
  const css = `div[data-autobot-element-id=DATEPICKER_DAY_${dateformat(date, 'yyyymmdd')}]`;
  browser
    .clickWaitForElementByCssWithCatch(css, isDisplayed, 30000, 1000)
    .nodeify(done);
};
module.exports.pickupDate = dateFunc;
module.exports.dropoffDate = datefunc;
```